# EF Core & ASP.NET Core 7 : get rid of a navigation field at result output

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I work on an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API using Entity Framework Core for the purpose.

There are two classes (`Post, Tag`) with navigation fields and the join class (`PostTag`) with no navigation fields:

[Post class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdDpJ.jpg)

[Tag class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RoOG.jpg)

[PostTag class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G886K.jpg)

Also there's the query that selects posts with tags

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Qan.jpg)

And the result output:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axXII.jpg)

As you can see a post contains tags list and the issue is that every tags contains a post that comes from `Tag` class navigation field.

The question - how do I get rid of these posts in the tag, I'd like to have `Titles` only, no posts at all?

Thanks for advance!

I tried to read the EF Core documentation and google the answer, no result.

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to the navigation field in Tag model:

```
public class Tag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public List<Post> posts { get; set; } = new();
    }
```

This attribute indicates whether an object is ignored when a reference cycle is detected during serialization.

Then when you use

```
return await _context.Post.Include(x=>x.tags).ToListAsync();
```

to select `Post` include `Tag`, It will ignore navigation field in Tag.

[image]

Comment: JsonIgnore - Many thanks!      What the doctor ordered! 
    'options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles' - Also, I tried to use this one but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the post navigation property on Tag or use Select to only select the properties you want.

You can also create DTO classes that only include the properties that you want and map the result to those objects. When the properties of the DTO classes have the same name as your enties you could use AutoMapper to do the mapping for you with the ProjectTo extension method. This will simplify things for you.

Comment: Thanks! Sure, I tried to remove the field but got the exception - "Invalid column name 'PostId'."

Comment: When the properties of the DTO classes have the same name as your enties you could use AutoMapper - Btw, nice idea! I'll try it...Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the error - "Error mapping types - Mapping types: Post -> PostDto ... Destination Member: Tag" while trying to map Post to PossDto if I remove the List<Post> field from Tag class

Comment: Can you please show me an example or a link to an article how to create the mapping for may case?

Comment: Hi Alex. Sorry for my late response but i was on vacation ;-)
You are getting the error because you have a navigation property to the Tag class instead of mapping to the TagDto class.

Create a PostDto class and a TagDto class.


    public class PostProfile : Profile
    {
        public PostProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Post, PostDto>();
        }
    }

    public class TagProfile : Profile
    {
        public TagProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Tag, TagDto>();
        }
    }

In the TagDto class leave out the navigation property to PostDto